# jQuery not working in html file (JS LINT errors such as '$' was used before it was defined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using HTML, CSS, and JS. I am trying to use the JQuery library but it is not being recognized by my html file. I am inserting it above my external .js file, so I don't think that is the issue. Here is what is in my HTML file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

This is what is in my JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 970) {
           $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        }
    });
});
```

My code editor is throwing errors when I save this js file because of errors like:

-'$' was used before it was defined.

-Expected exactly one space between 'fucntion and '('

Anyone know what the issue might be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ensure that the jQuery URL is correct. Perhaps it needs to be using the HTTPS protocol instead of HTTP?

Comment: @B.Fleming I tried using the HTTPS but it did not work, I am still getting the errors that I stated above in my .js file.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the issue, but you may wish to attempt to load the jquery file by HTTPS (`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js`), especially if you are running your site on an HTTPS connection.

Otherwise, it seems to work when I test it:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 970) {
        $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    }
  });
  console.log("done!")
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `<script>` tag, as @B.Fleming said maybe the `HTTPS` protocol. This tag is working:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

put this in top of your code where you are using jQuery

```
/* global $ */
```

alternativ is prefixing it with `window`

I don't like using the global $ sign cuz other libs are using it as well. what i usably dose is getting the $ from the closure function like this

```
jQuery(function($){
  // document is ready, You may use jquery here and now
  $('body')
})
```

and to get away with jQuery is not defined use `window.jQuery` instead

ps, always load stuff from https when possible